# Stream analytics time agnostic processing

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

my stream analytics jobs is not generating any output and watermark delay matrix keeps on increasing. for all other metrices like Input events, output events, cpu%(increases to 10%), runtime error, data conversion error there is no change (value is zero).

Input stream: 2 gb file in ADLS gen2. with file having multiple JSON objects (not JSON array)
Sample data:

```
{"a":"1"} //row 1
{"a":"2"}  // row 2
{"a":"1"} // row 3
```

The data doesn't have any time field to indicate event time.

output stream: Cosmos db

late event set to 5 sec
out of order event set to 25 sec.

Expected output: i want job to write to output every X mins.
current output: job is not writing any data to output and all metric values are zero

Thanks

Comment: Do you have one single file of 2GB? Because this is not how the blob/adls steaming input work. It ingest small files as they are created/uploaded over time. Can you tell me why you where considering ASA for that task? A batch engine like Azure Data Factory seems much more appropriate.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your Stream Analytics query; as written, there's no way to know how you set things up (including windowing). Also, it's not really clear how you're streaming data, if you're just consuming a single file.